# How to display an specific picture of an product on the product profile page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm making a product profile detail page and I don't know how to show the specific details of the product on that page..

For example I made this foreach loop to display all my products on a view page:

```
<?php foreach($cadeaus as $cadeau) : ?>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Productprofiel">
            <?php  echo '<img src="upload/'.$cadeau['product_foto'].'">' ; ?>
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $cadeau['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="product_beschrijving">
            <?php  echo $cadeau['product_beschrijving']; ?>
        </div>

        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see I'm linking to this page:  `<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Productprofiel">`

Now my question is, how can I display product items like pictures or titles on that product profile detail page view?

For example on that page I tried to echo the picture of the product but when I do the same like this:

```
<?php foreach($cadeaus as $cadeau) : ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="<?php echo base_url().'upload/'.$cadeau['product_foto'] ?>" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

it echo's all the product images and I only want to echo the product picture I clicked on

Comment: Then you are going to have to add the index of the image to the QueryString so you can get it in the code that shows it

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Productprofiel/"<?php echo $cadeau['id']` for example

Comment: I tried that code and its not working

Comment: It was just an example

Comment: Did you find solution for your question @lablanco if not ping back ill help you out

Comment: unfortunately not, I'm also not that experienced with PHP or CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

In this view use special link for each product

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Productprofiel/<?=$cadeau['product_id']?>">
```

In your controller(for me is 'admin') you need a function like this

```
public function Productprofiel($id){

$this->load->model('your_db_model');
$product_detail = $this->your_db_model->get_product_detail($id);
$data['product_detail'] = $product_detail;
$template['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/product_profile', $data, true);
$this->load->view('admin/template', $template);

}
```

`product_profile` is a view in your view folder.
in `your_db_model` select just one record and do not use `foreach` for `$product_detail` in your view page. It has just one record.

your view will be like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div><?=$product_detail['product_name'] ?></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url().'upload/'.$product_detail['product_foto'] ?>" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer I will try it out now

Comment: And what do I do if I don't have any admin template? I just leave this piece of code out: $template['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/product_profile', $data, true);
$this->load->view('admin/template', $template);       ?

Comment: actually you have a controller like admin witch your `$cadeaus` comes from.

Comment: you do not need have  folder similar admin in `admin/product_profile`. Remove admin and put your view template every where you like.

Comment: Replace this 2 lines $template['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/product_profile', $data, true);
$this->load->view('admin/template', $template);         with $this->load->view('product_profile', $data, true);

Comment: Was it helpful ? If not replay back i will help you again.